# move uploaded files into a folder

Tags: php

I'm trying to move uploaded files into a folder, but i can't do it. Somebody see the error?

My html code has this line:

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="save_new_article.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And this is php code:

```
include("bd.php");
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251');
$category = $_POST['category'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['full_description'];
$price = $_POST['price'];

$way = "../galery";
$file = $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'];
$file_name = $_FILES['photo']['name'];
$file_name = ext($file_name);

$way .= "/".$file_name;
move_uploaded_file($file,$way);
```

If somebody can detect the error, inform me please

Comment: What error do you get? Can the script write to the wanted directory (chmod)?

Comment: If I do "echo $way" it's gives me ../galery/fsdagdfgas12133.jpg
But the file is not in the folder

Comment: Completely unrelated, but if you don't want to store your files under their original name, you should just use a simple hashing algorithm for the filename or an increasing id instead of that.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
move_uploaded_file($file, $way);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the last line to:

```
move_uploaded_file($file, $way);
```

If you look at the docs for [move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php), you will see that the first parameter is the place where the file is currently. Aka `$_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']` which you have saved as `$file`.

Comment: You are wrong, read the documentation
move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination ), taken from your link

Comment: @IgorPatychenko - The `$filename` is referring to the temporary filename. If you scroll down on that page the first example shows them using `$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name']` for the first parameter. Have you tried my suggestion?

Comment: no, because it works with this line: move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination). The thing was in a permitions of the folder, but thanks